# Seeking free public LIDAR data of road in LAS format?

Tags: data, lidar, las, point-cloud-library

I am currently working on LiDAR point cloud road marking extraction.

Please help me to get relevant public dataset in LAS format?
Sample data is as shown in the image below: 
Data without original colour is also acceptable.

I am currently working on sample data provided by private organisation.

[image: sample data]

Comment: What part of the world are you interested in?

Comment: If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: I respectfully disagree with my esteemed colleague @PolyGeo:  I believe the community does welcome Open Data questions. More details on meta GIS SE: https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4155/8104.

Comment: @StuSmith I interested data with road markings, doesn't matter which part of world.

Comment: @PolyGeo Thanks, I was unaware about that.  I will ask on open data.

Answer (score 2):

I constructed a 24 billion point lidar point cloud web service available with color information that might be suitable for this task. It is available in [Entwine Point Tile](https://entwine.io/entwine-point-tile.html) format on AWS courtesy of [Bohannan Huston](https://www.bhinc.com/) and the [City of Hobbs, NM](https://www.hobbsnm.org/). You can view it in [Potree](http://potree.org) at https://hobbslidar.com.

The EPT resource link is https://na-c.entwine.io/coh/ept.json. Find out how to use EPT with [PDAL](https://pdal.io) at [readers.ept](https://pdal.io/stages/readers.ept.html).

Comment: If you do use this resource, please make sure to credit the sponsors far and wide. It was challenging to convince them to release such a dataset, and seeing the impact of that release might convince others to do the same

Answer (score 2):

You can download data in LAZ-format which you can covert to las from Lantmäteriet (~The Swedish National Land Survey) from [this link](https://www.lantmateriet.se/en/maps-and-geographic-information/open-geodata/). Create account and download via ftp. The lidar data is in folder "Laserdata_Skog". [Coverage](https://www.lantmateriet.se/sv/Kartor-och-geografisk-information/geodataprodukter/laserdata-skog/?steg=3) as of 2019-08-07:

[image]

- Green-ready to download
- Yellow-quality Control in progress
- Orange-scan finished
- Red-scan in progress

Comment: thanks for reply, I gone through the Swedish National Land Survey data. It is forest data capered by terrestrial laser scanner , I want road data captured with mobile lidar scanner on vehicle.

Comment: Ok you should edit your question and clarify that this is the data you want

Comment: data shared by you is also helpful for me. I will use it for my next goal.